# Laravel Passport, ERROR 403 | THE PROVIDED AUTH TOKEN FOR THE REQUEST IS DIFFERENT FROM THE SESSION AUTH TOKEN

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, single-sign-on, laravel-passport

I'm currently working on implementing a Single Sign-On (SSO) system using OAuth 2.0 with Laravel Passport in my Laravel application. However, I'm encountering an error that says "THE PROVIDED AUTH TOKEN FOR THE REQUEST IS DIFFERENT FROM THE SESSION AUTH TOKEN." whenever I try to authorize the sso client from sso server with the OAuth 2.0 flow.

Here's a brief overview of what I've done so far:

- Installed Laravel Passport and set up the necessary database migrations.
- Implemented OAuth routes for the authorization and token endpoints.
- Created a custom OAuth controller to handle the authorization and token issuance logic.
- Configured the Passport routes and guards in the AuthServiceProvider.
- Set up client registration and management.

Despite following the documentation and various tutorials, I'm still facing this error. I've tried debugging by checking the consistency of state parameters, verifying client credentials, and ensuring CSRF protection, but the issue persists.

I'm seeking assistance and advice from the community on how to troubleshoot and resolve this error effectively. If anyone has experience implementing SSO with Laravel Passport or OAuth 2.0 in general and can offer insights or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think we will need a bit more detail about the flow that is causing the error. Can you describe what steps do you take that led to this error? Is it possible for you to paste some code that would allow us to reproduce the error?